# unable to find serial port in java using jserialcomm

Tags: java

I want to create communication between serial port and java, since my real device is not arrived yet, so I use socat as people suggested on internet mostly.

I start with running socat first for virtual serial port with this command

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

then I get this

```
2018/12/05 05:05:04 socat[2687] N PTY is /dev/pts/4
2018/12/05 05:05:04 socat[2687] N PTY is /dev/pts/5
```

that's mean I could use /dev/pts/4 and /dev/pts/5 for port (NB: this is randomly given by socat, i don't know why)

and then I tried with python for communication with /dev/pts/4, and its work perfectly, then I use java with jSerialComm library I couldn't connect to /dev/pts/4, even cannot listed any ports.

```
SerialPort sp=SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/pts/4");
System.out.println(sp.isOpen());
```

my java code keeps returning false.
any response for this I'd appreciate it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you do `SerialPort sp=SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/pts/4");` you are getting the object that controls that port. The port however is still closed until you open it. This is done by doing `sp.openPort();`. Then you will see that when you run `sp.isOpen();` it should return true.

If you need further help the documentation can be found [here](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/package-summary.html).